# Socket.emit not going through

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

**index.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var users = [];

connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(require('express').static(path.join(__dirname)));

console.log('server running');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var addedUser = false;
    socket.on('new post', function(post){
        console.log(post);
        socket.emit('posted', data);
    }); 
});
```

**client.js**

```
$(function(){

    function submit(){
        socket.emit('new post', $("#text").val());
        console.log("submitted");   
    }

    function addPost(data){
        console.log(2);
        var $post = $('<p></p>').text(data);
        console.log($post);
        $("#posts").append($post);  
    }

    $("#submit").on("click", function(){
        submit();
    });

    socket.on('posted', function(data){
        console.log(1);
        addPost(data);  
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <input type="text" id="text">Input</input>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>


    <script src="client.js"></script>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div id="posts"></div>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

When I start up the server, the console logs "server running" fine. I can't get the submit post button to do anything. None of the debug console messages appear and nothing happens. It's supposed to emit "new post" when the submit button is clicked but it looks as if nothing goes through

Comment: What version of socket.io are you running on  your server?  Are you getting the `connection` event on the server?  Is your code in client.js getting called to set things up?

Comment: 4.1.2, and yes I'm getting the connection event. I put a console log after io.on('connection') and it runs. For your third question, do you mean if the submit button does anything? If so, it does. the function submit() runs and logs "submitted" in the client console

Comment: I don't think 4.1.2 is a socket.io version so I don't know what that is.  socket.io 2.0 just got released recently.  I'm trying to figure out if you have matching socket.io versions on client and server as that can be a reason that messages don't work.  If you change `<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>` to this `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` then it will load a matching socket.io client version from your server in case you have a version mismatch.

Comment: I put "npm socket.io --v" in console and it gave 4.1.2 but I think that's the express version. I don't know why it's giving that instead of the socket version

edit: will try the thing you edited in

Comment: Does nothing but now there's an error in client console. "GET <my 
 heroku site>.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LvJxD1q 503 (Service Unavailable)

Comment: Are you sure your heroku infrastructure is configured appropriately to allow webSocket/socket.io?  503 sounds suspicious to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your code to work on my own computer like this:

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var users = [];

connections = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

console.log('server running');


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("connection");
    socket.on('new post', function(post){
        console.log(post);
        socket.emit('posted', post);
    }); 
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

client.js

```
$(function(){

    function submit(){
        socket.emit('new post', $("#text").val());
        console.log("submitted");   
    }

    function addPost(data){
        console.log(2);
        var $post = $('<p></p>').text(data);
        console.log($post);
        $("#posts").append($post);  
    }

    $("#submit").on("click", function(){
        submit();
    });

    socket.on('posted', function(data){
        console.log(1);
        addPost(data);  
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <input type="text" id="text">Input</input>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>


    <script src="/client.js"></script>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div id="posts"></div>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**Changes to index.js**

1. Define `express` variable so it can be reused.
2. Define `app.get()` before `app.use(express.static(...))` so we're sure to serve index.html with the `app.get()` and not from the static location.
3. Change `res.sendfile()` to res.sendFile()`
4. Change `socket.emit("posted", data)` to `socket.emit("posted", post)`.
5. Move `server.listen()` to end after everything else is set up.
6. Remove `path.join()` from `express.static()` call since it is not needed there.
7. Add `path.join()` to `res.sendFile()` call for cross platform safety in path building.

Of these, the only one I'm sure was causing an error was #4, the others are good housekeeping.

**Changes to client.js**

None

**Changes to index.html**

Change path to client.js to `/client.js`.

---

If this code doesn't work on heroku, then you either don't have files positioned in the right directories or heroku is not configured properly to allow your app or socket.io to work properly.  If I were you, I would first verify that this code work on your own local computer and only then, go try it on heroku to eliminate variables first.